# mit dem or damit vor dem Nebensatz?

Tags: difference

Ich habe einen Satz gelesen, wie:

> Ich bin zufrieden mit dem, was ich habe.

Kann man das auch so schreiben:

> Ich bin zufrieden damit, was ich habe.

Was wäre der Unterschied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es geht nur

> Ich bin zufrieden mit dem, was ich habe. *bzw.*
>   Ich bin mit dem zufrieden, was ich habe.

*Damit* bezieht sich, wie von @user-unknown schon erwähnt, auf etwas bereits Bekanntes und ist sozusagen eine Abkürzung von *mit diesem*/*mit dieser Sache*:

> *Ich habe etwas.* Ich bin zufrieden damit. *bzw.* 
> Damit bin ich zufrieden.

**Ich bin zufrieden damit, was ich habe.* ist nicht richtig.

Answer (score -1):

Der Unterschied ist folgender:

> Ich bin zufrieden mit dem, was ich habe.

Hier bezieht sich der Nebensatz auf das 'dem' -> das, was ich habe

> Ich bin zufrieden damit, dass ich etwas habe.

"Ich bin damit zufrieden" wäre schon ein vollständiger Satz, der Nebensatz danach ist nur zusätzliche Information, und leitet dadurch einen Objektsatz ein. Im ersten Satz ist der Nebensatz jedoch zwingend, um das 'dem' zu bezeichnen. Hierbei handelt es sich bei dem Nebensatz um einen Relativ- bzw. Attributsatz und beschreibt damit ein Substantiv oder etwas, das es ersetzt.
(wie in diesem Satz gerade eben)
Es handelt sich hier um unterschiedliche Arten von Nebensätzen.

Rein technisch gesehen wären also tatsächlich beide korrekt, jedoch hat "damit" eine gewisse Sonderrolle inne. Üblicherweise kann man einen Objektsatz sehr gut mit 'mit' einleiten. "damit" ist dagegen eine Fusion mit 'mit', wodurch es sich etwas anders verhält.

Comment: "Ich bin damit zufrieden" setzt aber voraus, dass das "damit" bekannt ist, also im Satz davor näher bezeichnet wurde, was im alternativen Satz mit dem "mit dem" nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Hab jetzt die Begriffe gegoogelt. Besser?

Comment: Man könnte meinen das *dass* da sei überflüssig. *Ich bin zufrieden, dass ich etwas habe*. Ich bin außerdem der Ansicht, *dass* sei ein fauler Behelf und darüber hinaus würde *damit dass*, wenn überhaup verstanden, als feste Wendung verstanden werden ähnlich *so dass*, weshalb das Komma dazwischen nicht den eigentlichen Sprachfluss reflektiert.

Comment: Nach Grammatikregeln muss das Komma an diese Stelle. Geschriebenes != Sprachfluss.